# ojdbc: tomcat/weblogic: How to reset cusror for connection metadata

Tags: java, jdbc, database-metadata

Trying to get the column's metadata from connection/database metadata. Any way to use `rs.beforeFirst()` or any alternative to move back the cursor?

Following is code snippet:

```
ResultSet rs= read_conn.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, 
sourceTableName.toUpperCase(), null);

while (rs.next()){ ... }

rs.beforeFirst();  /* Error:17075. Assuming DatabaseMetaData's resultset is 
ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY*/
```

Reference:

- [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)
- Connection is opened/configured using JNDI DataSources on Tomcat 7/8 and WebLogic 11/12.

Answer (score 1):

Fromm [ResultSet Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only.

So `rs.beforeFirst()` should be used first like this:

```
rs.beforeFirst();
while ( rs.next()) {
   String id = rs.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: Requirement is, iterate the DatabaseMetaData related getColumns multiple times. So any way to change default settings from forwards-only to scroll-insensitive, specific to one generated by:           read_conn.getMetaData().getColumns(...);